# Taking a Snapshot of Firebase Data and Storing the Data

Tags: ios, json, parsing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JSON Firebase database:

```
{ "fruits": {
        "apple": {
            "name": "Gala",
            "url": "//s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/3e/b1/e7/3eb1e756d66856975d6e43ebb879200a.jpg",
            "fruitArray": [1, 2]
        },
       "orange": {
             "name": "Tangerine",
             "url": "//userscontent2.emaze.com/images/0ba588c8-42d9-45e9-a843-d19e5720515a/e430f9a827f139e9f99f2826175dd0a9.jpg",
             "fruitArray": []
        } 
    }
}
```

the following Fruit class:

```
class Fruit {
     var name: String
     var url: String
     var fruitArray: [Int]
     var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    init(name: String, url: String, fruitArray: [Int]) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
        self.fruitArray = fruitArray
        self.ref = nil
    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        url = snapshotValue["url"] as! String
        if snapshotValue["fruitArray"] == nil {
            fruitArray = [0]
        } else {
            fruitArray = snapshotValue["fruitArray"] as! [Int]
        }
        ref = snapshot.ref
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "url": url,
            "fruitArray": fruitArray
        ]
    }
```

And the following FruitTableViewController Code:

```
class FruitTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var fruits: [Fruit] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "fruits")

        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var addedFruits: [Fruit] = []

            for fruit in snapshot.children {
                let newFruit = Fruit(snapshot: fruit as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                addedFruit.append(newFruit)
            }

            self.fruits = addedFruits

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? FruitTableViewCell 

        let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
        let imgURL = NSURL(string: fruit.url)

        if imgURL != nil {
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: (imgURL as? URL)!)
            cell.icon.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = fruit.name

        return cell
    }
```

For some reason, the Firebase snapshot is not working. I've tried almost everything with no luck.

It's not a TableViewCell issue (I think) because I checked the FruitViewCell and Storyboard and everything is in order. My hunch is that it has something to do with the way I'm changing the URL to a string as well as the array. I've used this exact code for a different iOS project and it worked but the difference between the two projects is that this one has an array and link within the JSON while the other one didn't.

I've seen that there are other ways to take a snapshot but I'm going to use the fruit data throughout the app and thus it's easier for me to have a Fruit object, but I wouldn't mid if someone were to suggest an alternate way of taking a snapshot that works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: first of all your fruitArray is not string .. its an array

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I know, but I couldn't figure out a way to initialize the snapshot in the Fruit object by keeping the array and url as is.

Comment: something like https://paste.ofcode.org/MyhqPYaLuGtcWUj6w99ncF

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I implemented what you suggested in the Fruit class and got no errors but the snapshot still won't work.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 no output in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135433/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-ch1maera).

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I posted an update in the chat if you're still on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your `viewDidLoad` with this code as addedFruites is not needed at all

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("fruits")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            for fruit in snapshot.children {
            let newFruit = Fruit(snapshot: fruit as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            self.fruits.append(newFruit)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    })
}
```

> check firebase rules for read and write is properly set or not.. I think here is an issue because may be you did not set that rules.